# Using @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject})) making a part of code unreachable

Tags: java, spring, guice, lombok

When using Lombok's::`@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@javax.inject.Inject}))` instead of guice's::`@Inject` a part of code is getting unreachable. Test cases are failing due to null pointer(code unreachable). The bean that is getting injected in the constructor is:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Inject
EntryDao getEntryDao(
            @Named("dynamoDBEncryptionLoggingMapper") DynamoDBLoggingMapper dynamoDBMapper){
    return new EntryDao(dynamoDBMapper);
}
```

Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: Could you provide more code info? It's kind of hard to understand. Also, you use Guice, Spring and Lombok, according to the tags? Then we need to know where the getEntryDao is defined in a Guice Module or in a Spring config? Can you show (part of) your class that has the Lombok annotation? There's way too much missing info for us to help you.

Comment: Some long time ago I replaced all occurrences of Guice's `@Inject` by `@javax.inject.Inject` and everything worked as before. I'd bet, even a mixture should work as there's nothing but testing the annotation presence in Guice. You need to decompose the problem, e.g., make a demo project, delombok it, so that you see whether it may be the culprit.

Comment: If I delombok it (remove `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@javax.inject.Inject})`) and use a simple @inject with the constructor, the code works as expected.